# Adding a exception on the client side of OpenVPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have an openvpn client and it's configuration is stored in a .ovpn file. All my network traffic is going through the VPN tunnel when I connect to it.

I want to add an exception for some of the IPs to not go through the VPN tunnel. I have tried adding `route www.google.com 255.255.255.255 192.168.43.1` at the end of the ovpn file to test it. (192.168.43.1 is router IP address)

But, this is making the configuration file invalid. I am just beginning to learn openvpn and I am confused about where to add this line exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think route can only be used with IPs not with DNS names...

Comment: [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91071/212783) does it by `push route` in the server config but it should be the same syntax for the client config using only `route`